# Acidentally deleted `/usr/bin/ipython` after `ImportError: No module named Shell` when running ipython from virtual environment

Tags: installation, ipython

**Preface**

I had a system-wide installation of Ipython which was working fine. However, when I was working in a virtual environment and had to install ipython there, running it from there gave the following error:

```
File "/usr/bin/ipython", line 26, in <module>
    import IPython.Shell
ImportError: No module named Shell
```

**Current problem**

Unfortunately I accidently removed the `ipython` file in `/usr/bin`. So calling `ipython` from inside or outside the virtual environment now gives this error:

```
bash: /usr/bin/ipython: No such file or directory
```

The following ipython-related files are currently in `/usr/bin`:

```
/usr/bin$ find ipython*
ipython2.6
ipython2.7
ipython-wx
ipythonx
```

If I remove all these files, will a fresh system-wide ipython install reinstall these files?
(I have my doubts since I reinstalled it and it didn't add the deleted `ipython` file. in `/usr/bin`)

What should I do to fix this?

**Extra info**

I am using python2.7

**Edit**

When I replace the first line of the new `/usr/bin/ipython` file to `#!/usr/bin/python` as Monir suggested I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ipython", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2676, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 552, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: ipython==0.13.1
```

Comment: Have you tried searching for the ipython executable inside the virtual env and copying it to /usr/bin ? If the system-wide ipython version was same as the one installed in the virtual env, this should work.

Comment: Thanks, this also solved my previous problem. I just had to delete `/home/username/.ipython/ipythonrc` after that and everything was fine. Could you post a seperate response so I can accept it as an anwser?

Comment: great, I just posted it as answer.

Comment: I suspect the system version of ipython was not 0.13.1, which is teh version in your virtualenv. Try searching for ipython * inside your /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/.

my system has python 2.6, and I see a /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ipython-0.13.1-py2.6.egg  which  gives me the python version to use in /usr/bin/ipython.

In case these all fails, try reinstalling ipython at system level. Not sure if you already tried that in the first place.

Comment: It seems I had ipython installed using `apt-get install` and `pip install` at the same time. I think these two were conflicting. I did `sudo apt-get --purge remove ipython` then `sudo pip uninstall ipython` and then installed ipython from the tar.gz file. Now everything works fine. If you would just copy part of this answer in your answer I can accept it.

Comment: great, glad that it is fixed. I have copied the part into the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- putting as answer to close this qn--

Try searching for the ipython executable inside the virtual env and copying it to /usr/bin.  If the system-wide ipython version was same as the one installed in the virtual env, this should work.

As requested, I am pasting my /us/bin/ipython:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'ipython==0.13.1','console_scripts','ipython'
__requires__ = 'ipython==0.13.1'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

sys.exit(
   load_entry_point('ipython==0.13.1', 'console_scripts', 'ipython')()
)
```

This is pointing to system python, so has access to necessary system-wide packages instead of the virtual env python. Run a "which python" on a directory outside your virtualenv and put that path in the first line after the sha-bang. (most probably it wil be /usr/bin/pyhton)

--Update: pasting part from recent comment to get this answer accepted and the qn closed.

If all else fails, try reinstalling ipython at system level. Not sure if you already tried that in the first place.

Comment: I am able to run ipython but not import my system-wide installed packages. That's because its pointing to the virtual environment I copied the script from I guess. I tried modifying it but can't seem to make it work properly. could you paste the content of your `/usr/bin/ipython` file? Here is the one I copied: http://pastebin.com./iPdL8yRq

Comment: ah, only difference is my iptyhon has the first line pointing to /usr/bin/python, see my updated answer. Please accept the answer if this solves your issue, so this qn gets closed.

Comment: I get an error when I do that. (I ran ´which python´, +1 for that) See the edit of my original post. Btw I will accept your answer if I can resolve the issue.